# Flusing TCP after boost::asio::write

Tags: c++, tcp, boost-asio, flush

I have simple server written with boost:.asio

```
boost::asio::io_context io_context;
tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port));
tcp::socket socket(io_context);
acceptor.accept(socket);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay option(true);
socket.set_option(option);

for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
  boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer("Hello, World!"), ignored_error);
}
```

My Problem is now that all 10 lines are send at once. But I want to have 10 separate messages. I thought `boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay` would help. But it does not.

The nodejs client I tested this looked:

```
import * as net from 'net';

const client = new net.Socket();

client.connect(3232, 'localhost', () => {
    console.log('Connected');
});

client.on('data', data => {
    console.log(`Received: ${data}`);
});


client.on('close', () => {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

`client.on('data', ...)` was only called once here.

Does anyone know how to "flush" after write?

Or is this a mistake in the nodejs client implementation?

Comment: 'My Problem is now that all 10 lines are send at once.' no, your problem is that you dont understand the octet, (byte), streaming nature of TCP.  If you want discrete messages, (application protocol units). longer than one byte, you will need an appropriate protocol on top of TCP.

Answer (score 2):

TCP conceptually is a streaming protocol and has no concept of datagrams (unlike UDP). Once data is added to the TCP buffer, it will be sent in as few IP packets as possible. Also at the other end, all incoming packets boundaries info is lost. All incoming data is consolidated into a single buffer. So if you need framing, you need to implement it at the application level.

Comment: I've seen this answer several times, but still I can't make it work. The server doesn't read the message until I kill the client, so I supposed there was some flushing needed

Comment: Might need to disable the Nagle Algorithm (TCP_NODELAY)